# Is there a python function to return a new dict with a new key added, like assoc in clojure?

Tags: python, dictionary, clojure, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I'm writing python after writing clojure for a while, and I'm a little rusty, but I am approaching it in a much more functional style. To follow a pattern I used in clojure, I want to use map (or list comprehension) with something like [assoc](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc) to set keys in each dict in a list.

I have a list of records, and I want to restructure them with list comprehensions.

The record looks like this:

```
{
  "timestamp":1232435235315,
  "data": {
    "foo": 2345,
    "bar": 1454
  }
}
```

I want to get a dict containing the timestamp and the keys from data.

```
newlist = [ assoc(x, "timestamp", x["timestamp"]) for x in mylist ]
```

I could implement an assoc pretty easily, but I'd like for it to exist already in a library:

```
def assoc(coll, k, v):
  newcoll = coll.copy()
  newcoll[k] = v
  return newcoll
```

Does anyone out there know a library which already contains something like this or a pythonic way to do it concisely without mutating the original list?

Comment: No, but if someone has a library, it establishes a pattern and probably has other functions in it that would be similarly useful. I wouldn't mind having a pythonic version of many things in clojure.core. I could write such a library, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if someone else already has one.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Sure, you can simply use `dict()`, for example:

```
old = {"a": 1}
new_one = dict(old, new_key=value)
#or
new_one = dict(old, {...})
```

Comment: One thing to be careful of with this is that it will not deep-copy values, so any references will be shared between the two dictionaries.

Comment: Yea, thanks to @ryachza. If you really want a deep copy, you can use `from copy import deepcopy` and then `new_one = deepcopy(dict(old, new_key=value))`.

Comment: I am using this in my code now. The structures I'm mapping lately don't need deep copy, but it's important to be aware of the gotchas. Thanks Sraw and @ryachza.

Comment: Is this code python-version dependent? In python 3.9.0 evaluating a `dict({}, {1 : 3})` results in `TypeError: dict expected at most 1 argument, got 2`.

Comment: "it will not deep-copy values", this is a win for Clojure. I never have to think about this.

Comment: This solution does not have the same performance characteristics as clojure's assoc though, namely constant-time addition of an extra key. I didn't actually RTFM but if you play around on the REPL (Python 3.8) with some reasonably-large dicts this is easily observable.

Comment: @Hi-Angel note how the answer you're replying to makes use of keyword arguments

Comment: @Hi-Angel In python 3 a double star before inner dict is required : `new_one = dict(old, **{...})`. 
But in python 3.9 dictionary merging is easier as syltruong said in another answer

Answer (score 16):

Since Python 3.9, you can also use [Dictionary Merge and Update Operators](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#dictionary-merge-update-operators), although some may argue that is less explicit.

The code snippet would become:

```py
old = {"a": 1}


# 1. Merge operator

new_one = old | {"new_key": value}
## `old_one` is {"a": 1}
## `new_one` is {"a": 1, "new_key": value}


# 2. Update operator

old |= {"new_key": value}
## `old_one` becomes {"a": 1, "new_key": value}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the accepted answer throws

> TypeError: dict expected at most 1 argument, got 2

If one can not use Python 3.9 for whatever reason one can define a function which looks the following

```
def dict_update(x, **kwargs):
    y = x.copy()
    y.update(kwargs)
    return y

old = {"a", 1}

new = dict_update(old, b=2, c=3)

print(old)
>>> {"a": 1}
print(new)
>>> {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
```

Comment: This solution will also update `old`, which I don't think the question author want.

Comment: edited the answer thanks to the comment of @Conchylicultor

Answer (score 0):

If you want this with similar performance characteristics as in Clojure [PEP 603 (draft)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0603/) seems to be the way forward. As of early 2021 this PEP is not accepted, but a full implementation exists: https://github.com/MagicStack/immutables